# Java how to check if ResourceBundle is valid (expired or cleared from cache)

Tags: java, resourcebundle

Java how to check if ResourceBundle is valid (expired or cleared from cache)?

```
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName, locale, ...);

resourceBundle.getString("abc");
```

The resourceBundle can be expired or have been removed from cache. How to check it before calling getString(...) method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `ResourceBundle.Control.getTimeToLive(...)` and `ResourceBundle.Control.needsReload(...)`

Java 11 Docs here:

[getTimeToLive](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html#getTimeToLive(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale))

[needsReload](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html#needsReload(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale,java.lang.String,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.util.ResourceBundle,long))

Comment: Thanks. So resourceBundle can not be cached locally as a class member? If timeToLive is too long, have to wait for a long time to see changes on disk. If too short, performance overhead.